# Not able to pass ng-repeat value into custom directive from table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass `ng-repeat` value from table into directive, but it is not working. In `custom-elememt` directive, I want to pass the `ng-repeat` value into it, but it is not take `ng-repeat` value. But If I try the same thin in `div` that is working, So Why I am not able to pass `ng-repeat` value into customer directive from table.

**Not Working**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="entry in entries track by $index">
    <tr>
       <td>  {{ entry.id }}></td>
       <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <products-table products="entry.products"></products-table>
</tbody>
```

**Working**

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries">
    <products-table products="entry.products"></products-table>
</div>
```

Please find the demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/DFMvhm6CoZTs1PigloT3?p=preview

Comment: Your markup is all kinds of messed up. Why don't you show how you'd like the end result to look?

Comment: Reason, is that I want to expand the table, It not yet complete.

Comment: But you've got another table in the directive's template.

Answer (score 1):

Put your directive within table cell.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="entry in entries track by $index">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <products-table products="entry.products"></products-table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since *entry.products* is an array of objects,
you will have to apply another ng-repeat for that.

Your code will become

```
<tbody ng-repeat="entry in entries track by $index">
  <tr ng-repeat="product in entry.products">
    <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
  </tr>
  <products-table products="entry.products"></products-table>
</tbody>
```

Comment: The product repeater is in the directive template

Answer (score 0):

In a table tbody can render content which is in tr. You cannot render any elements like div or span outside of tr

```
<tbody ng-repeat="entry in entries track by $index">
    <tr>
        <td>  {{ entry.id }}></td>
        <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
        <td><products-table products="entry.products"></products-table><td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: you can give that products-table in tr also

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY), the TBODY element can contain only TR elements. If you write `<div>foo</div>` inside the `<tbody>` for example, the DOM simply renders it and paste the Element above your table (as you can see in your plunkr). Thereby your directive is outside your ng-repeat scope and nothing can be shown.